# Connect to DB and Activites by OOP in PHP

Tags: php, oop, mysqli, this

Hi I am having some issues connecting to my DB using OO PHP. My script is below. I have been going at this for a while now. This is just a test script as I am fairly new to OOP. Please don't be harsh

```
class Database{

    public $mysqli,
         $host,
         $username,
         $password,
         $db;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){

      $this->host = $host;
      $this->username = $username;
      $this->password = $password;
      $this->db = $db;

     $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);
        if (!$mysqli){
            echo "error in connecting to database";
        }
        else{
            echo "success in connecting to database";
        }
    }   

    public function query(){
        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM inventory");
        if ($result) {
            printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

            $result->close();
        }
        else{
            echo "there is an error in query";
            $result->close();
        }
        //echo "in query function";
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
$DB = new Database('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx', 'yyyy');
$DB -> query();
```

Comment: If you're *"having some issues"*, you need to add all available information in your question. **Describe the problem and the symptoms** otherwise it makes it very hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is that you aren't storing a value into your class' `$mysqli` property. You need to use `$this->mysqli` in your constructor and query method instead of `$mysqli`.

Secondly, this class adds **nothing** that the `mysqli` class doesn't already have. You might as well simply use

```
$DB = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx', 'yyyy');

if ($DB->connect_error) {
    throw new Exception($DB->connect_error, $DB->connect_errno);
}
```

Comment: which is better pdo or mysqli>

Comment: @user2128444 That's entirely subjective. I think PDO has a cleaner API however there's some MySQL features that can only be used via MySQLi so you would choose based on how you were going to use the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are accessing the class property without `$this`. The `$mysqli` should be in `$this->mysqli` in constructor function.

You are using **mysqli** property as **Object** of `mysqli` **class**.

Then you can use the **query** function of **mysqli property object**(In Database class) by `$this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM inventory")` in query function.

**Updated Code:**

```
<?php
class Database{

    public $mysqli,
         $host,
         $username,
         $password,
         $db;

public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $db){

  $this->host = $host;
  $this->username = $username;
  $this->password = $password;
  $this->db = $db;

 $this->mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db);

    /* check connection */
    if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
       printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $this->mysqli->connect_error);
       exit();
    } else {
       echo "success in connecting to database";
    }
}   

public function query(){
    $result = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM inventory");
    if ($result) {
        printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

        $result->close();
    }
    else{
        echo "there is an error in query";
        $result->close();
    }
    //echo "in query function";
}
}

$DB = new Database('localhost', 'root', 'xxxx', 'yyyy');
$DB -> query();
```

Comment: A failed `mysqli` constructor will not evaluate to a *falsey* value. You need to check the value of `mysqli::$connect_error` / `mysqli::$connect_errno`

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

// Test if connection succeeded
if(mysqli_connect_error()){
    die("Database connection failed: " .
        mysqli_connect_error() .
        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
}
```

Comment: isn't that procedural?